# Powershell Install Office Script Unknown Error and RemoteRegistry cannont open

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install Microsoft Office using powershell. Unfortunately I am running into two errors that I cannot figure out how to fix. Will someone please guide me into the right direction?

**Script**

```
Function Get-FileName{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "|*.*",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = "C:\")

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$file = Get-FileName -InitialDirectory $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop -Filter "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
ForEach ($item in (Get-Content $file)) {
    $sitem = $item.Split("|")
    $computer = $sitem[0].Trim()
    $user = $sitem[1].Trim()

    $filepath = Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\"
    If ($filepath -eq $false) {
    Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service

    Copy-Item -Path "\\server\Install\Office2010" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\windows\temp\" -Container -Recurse -Force

    $InstallString = '"C:\windows\temp\Office2010\setup.exe"'
    ([WMICLASS]"\\$computer\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Process").Create($InstallString)

    "$computer" + "-" + "$(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Install\Office2010\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append

    } Else {
        "$computer" + "_Already_Had_Software_" + "$(Get-Date)" | Out-File -FilePath "\\server\Install\Office2010\RemoteInstallfile.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

**Errors**

```
Start-Service : Service 'Remote Registry (remoteregistry)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open remoteregistry service on computer 'IT-Tech'.
At line:23 char:58
+     Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand



__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 2
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ProcessId        : 
ReturnValue      : 8
PSComputerName   :
```

Will someone please help me figure this out, I have been struggling on this for days!?

Comment: Your first error likely means that you don't have rights to start that service, do you have admin rights on that computer? 

As for Win32_Process.Create(), the largest issue that you are going to run into is that setup.exe requires an interactive session. [This previous post](http://serverfault.com/questions/690852/use-powershell-to-start-a-gui-program-on-a-remote-machine) gives a good run down on the issue.

Comment: yes i have admin rights on the computer

Comment: is there a command i can input to see what my rights are then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure when you open up powershell (or run the ps1 file. Whichever your application may be) you right click it and click run as administrator.

As for your install script, have you tried running it as a service? You won't have to enable the remote registry service if you do it this way:

```
Copy-item "\\servershare\Office 2010" -conatiner -recurse \\computer\c$\windows\temp\
Invoke-Command -Computername computer -ScriptBlock {
    Start-process "C:\windows\temp\office 2010\setup.exe"}
```

Here's the reference to that [script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1f8c02fb-1c11-478d-846d-571cc370b7d1/install-software-remotely-via-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell). 
See if that gives you different results. If not then something is up with your admin permissions. Either the account you're running the script from is not a member of the local admins group on the target computer or it's not a local admin on the computer you're running it from.

It's also wise to have a .msp file to configure and install office with from a script if you want the installation to run silently without any user interaction required. If you've not created an msp file, Microsoft's website explains it with step by step instructions.

Comment: right clicking running as administrator made it work

Comment: also is -conatiner misspelled or is this also a command iv seen it multiple times the same exact way i always just thought it was misspelled

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it's -container. My bad on that.